# do.call("rbind", list(data, frames)) but also index each row by its original data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 5:6, b = 7:8)

# A common method loses the origin of each row.
do.call("rbind", list(df1, df2))
##   a b
## 1 1 3
## 2 2 4
## 3 5 7
## 4 6 8

# Whereas here, X1 records which data frame each row originated in.
library(plyr)
adply(list(df1, df2), 1)
##   X1 a b
## 1  1 1 3
## 2  1 2 4
## 3  2 5 7
## 4  2 6 8
```

Are there any other ways to do this, perhaps more efficient?

Comment: I don't know if more efficient, but if `l <- list(df1, df2)` is your list, you could potentially create an index using `Map`, e.g., `l <- Map(cbind, l, indx = seq_len(length(l)))`

Comment: `reshape2::melt(list(df1,df2),1:2)` is another option

Comment: Is there a way to legitimize this question for the sake of the answers, which are substantially different from the others?

Comment: @nacnudus - It is legitimite! It will still stay here, it just is now linked to the other question so that people who find one can find the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

foo <- list(df1, df2)

unnest(foo, names) %>%
mutate(names = gsub("^X", "", names))

#  names a b
#1     1 1 3
#2     1 2 4
#3     2 5 7
#4     2 6 8
```

Comment: hmmm, `names`? what sorcery is that?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was looking for a way to add data.frame names to a bound data.frame. I, then, found this usage of `unnest` a while ago in one of the SO answers. The column name does not have to be `names`. It can be `david`, for example.

Comment: That's pretty slick.  You could even just leave it as `unnest(foo, names)`

Comment: @RichardScriven Yeah, you are right. I just wanted to deliver the expected outcome. The `mutate` part cab be optional.

Comment: Pretty slick indeed. Maybe worth adding to `data.table::rbindlist`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I agree with you. This is a tiny but pretty useful thing for data.table as well. I wonder if Arun has something in the pipeline.

Comment: I doubt that. He probably have more urgent stuff to do.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah I am pretty sure. But, we could make a request. :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. I get Error in UseMethod("unnest_") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest_' applied to an object of class "list".

Comment: It was however added to rbindlist as discussed above.

Comment: @JanStanstrup Yeah I noticed that `unnest()` is not working as it used to be. Thanks for leaving your comment. This will help other users from now on. :)

Answer (score 1):

With base:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 5:6, b = 7:8)

frames <- list(df1, df2)

do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(frames), function(x) {
  frames[[x]]$X1 <- x
  frames[[x]]
}))

##   a b X1
## 1 1 3  1
## 2 2 4  1
## 3 5 7  2
## 4 6 8  2
```

As an aside, if you want to see how `plyr` does this have a gander at `(plyr::adply)`, `(plyr:::splitter_a)` & `(plyr::ldply)`. These answers are trivial compared to that :-)